# Installing gitosis and closed port?

Tags: port, git, connection-refused

I'm trying to install gitosis on a Server (hosted by OVH and running Ubuntu server 11.04). I've done it a few times and never had any problems.

But this time I have something very wired when I simply try to clone gitosis.

```
[root@ovks-1:~/]#git clone git://eagain.net/gitosis.git
Cloning into gitosis...
eagain.net[0: 208.78.102.120]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
zsh: exit 128   git clone git://eagain.net/gitosis.git
```

Based on my searches [it looks like the port 9418 is closed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015732/why-do-i-get-unable-to-connect-a-socket-when-i-try-to-clone-via-a-git-url)

But I don't understand, a server by definition shouldn't have any closed port and I can't find a way to see if they are.

So how can I check is a port is open and how can I open it if closed?

Thank you for your help.

---

Requested by WesleyDavid: `iptables -L` result

```
[root@odeoos-vks-1:~/]#iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have no idea what it means... Thanks :)

---

Update:

I finally cloned gitosis from github using `https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis.git` and it worked.

**My guess is that `eagain.net` has an actual connection problem and that there isn't much I could do about it...**

Comment: Whelp... doesn't look like its iptables since it's flushed. Is there even a git daemon listening on the port? `netstat -va | grep 9148`

Answer (score 6):

> But I don't understand, a server by definition shouldn't have any
>   closed port and I can't find a way to see if they are.

I think you are slightly mistaken. A server, by definition, serves. What it serves is chosen by the server administrator. Technically, a server can have all of its ports closed, although that wouldn't be a very useful server... unless it was serving things internally between services.

> So how can I check is a port is open and how can I open it if closed?

The classic way of determining if a port is open is to telnet to that port and see what banner, if any, you receive. I just tried to telnet to the server you listed and the connection was immediately refused:

```
[wesley@Fedora1530 ~]$ telnet eagain.net 9418
Trying 208.78.102.120...
telnet: connect to address 208.78.102.120: Connection refused
```

A more robust way is to use a port scanning and fingerprinting tool like [nmap](http://nmap.org/). You can use a GUI front-end if you want it to be friendlier (example: [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/)). I'd scan that server, except it's not mine and that can be construed as hostile, so I'll leave that as an exercise for you, the original poster. =)

From where I sit, it does indeed look like there is some blockage of port 9418 between you and the git server at eagain.net - and between *me* and eagen.net for that matter. Contact the server/site operator and ask him *"What the dilly, yo?!"*

---

I'm a little slow on the draw tonight, and just realized that you are the server operator. So... *"What the dilly, yo?!"*

Anyway, you need to check iptables for any rules that would be blocking git traffic. Run `iptables -L` and post the results in your answer.

Comment: Haha very nice post thank you :) Actually I'm not the server operator (at least not the one behind eagain.net). I'm just trying to clone a repository located on eagain.net server. This said it looks like my server (odeoos.com) also has the port 9418 closed. And I don't know why.

Comment: Wait no I'm stupid it makes total sence. I have nothing waiting for a connection on the port 9418 on my server (odeoos.com) so the connection can only be refused... Anyway eagain.net should have a git deamon if I understand well...

Comment: `iptables -L` knows all! Sees all!

Comment: Added to my question :)